# How does one "Press 1 for English" using voice on iPhone during call with phone system menu?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

Is there a way to use my voice to "press" a button on the numeric keypad during a phone call, resulting in my handset sending the appropriate DTMF codes to the device on the other end?

I like to conduct business while riding my bike, and Siri can help me with most requests hands-free. However, interacting with a phone system on the other end seems to be where her assistance hits a hard stop -- I can't find a way to have Siri "press 1" or anything to that effect during a phone call.

While some phone systems accept voice input, many still rely upon DTMF tones to be sent through during the call to select certain menu items. Many times, hands are unavailable, and being prompted for keypad input can be frustrating and dangerous.

Is there a way to, for example, have Siri listen to calls for commands like "Siri, press one five one pound", to send the DTMF codes "151#" on behalf of my hands?

Comment: Bear in mind that if Siri is listening to any part of the call, All of what you are saying or discussing would be sent to Apple for that part of the call.

Comment: I did suppose that she did have some rudimentary voice recognition capability built in for offline use, like "call", or "voicemail". Regarding this bounty, there is still the three-button headset remote that doesn't require physical access to the phone in my pocket.

Comment: are the numbers you are dealing that need these DTMF numbers always the same or are you calling different numbers each time

Answer (score 6):

If the numbers are in your contacts.

You can Edit the contact by adding another number with some controls in.

i.e if you are always dialling : (888) 555 1212

And you need to wait 4 seconds and then enter a (1) for the selection.

---

You can Edit the contact and duplicate the number.

Then press the symbols button.

[image]

which will give you two new buttons.

**Pause** and **Wait**.

Pressing the **Pause** button will add a "," at the end of the number.

AFAIK each "," will pause for 2 seconds. I am not sure about wait. Which I expect will be longer.

[image]

Once you have your pauses you can add the DTMF number as shown I have entered two "," to get 4 seconds and a (1) for the DTMF.

[image]

Repeat as needed for any other pauses and numbers and save. And dail.

Comment: This is a great way to handle the situation if "the menu options *haven't* recently changed to serve me better"! Although I am specifically looking for a way to whimsically "press" buttons to navigate a phone system menu, this is pretty neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible without a jailbreak, and even with a jailbreak there are currently no tweaks which allow you to do this.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: Jailbreaks are welcome, and remember there are three headphone buttons available that do not require taking my phone out of my pocket, which is what I am looking for. Partial answers are also worthy of bounty if the puzzle is solved. If nary a bounty hunter can see a way to do this for a few weeks, the bounty will be yours de facto.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a bit late, but I had the same issue and what I did was pressing the number and holding it, that worked for me.